# Convert JSON POST Object to Array of Strings in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, post, flask

I'm having trouble creating an array of strings that takes a JSON Object when I send POST request like below:

```
{ "inList" : [ { "smarter" : [ "Einstein", "Feynmann" ] },
{ "smarter" : [ "Feynmann","Gell-Mann"]},
{ "smarter":  [ "Gell-Mann","Thorne"]},
{ "smarter" : [ "Einstein","Lorentz"]}, 
{ "smarter" : [ "Lorentz","Planck"]}, 
{ "smarter" : [ "Hilbert","Noether"]}, 
{ "smarter" : [ "Poincare","Noether"]}
]}
```

I'm trying to sort the names so that anyone who appears in the first element of the smarter pair will have their name printed before in the response output.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/postjson', methods = ['POST'])
def postJsonHandler(self):
    candidates = set()
    nodes = {}
    sorted = []
    self.incoming = set()
    self.outgoing = set()
   if request.json:
    smarter[] = json.loads(inList['smarter'])
    for l in smarter[]:
    p1,p2 = tuple([s.strip() for s in l.split(":")])

    if p1 not in nodes:
        nodes[p1] = Node()

    if p2 not in nodes:
        nodes[p2] = Node()

    nodes[p1].outgoing.add(p2)
    nodes[p2].incoming.add(p1)

    if len(nodes[p1].incoming)==0:
       candidates.add(p1)

    candidates.discard(p2)
    while len(candidates)>0:
        candidate = candidates.pop()
        sorted.append(candidate)

        while len(nodes[candidate].outgoing)>0:
            out = nodes[candidate].outgoing.pop()
            nodes[out].incoming.remove(candidate)

            if len(nodes[out].incoming)==0:
               candidates.add(out)

     print sortedhello

    return sortedhello(['smarter'])
   else:
    return "no json"
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 8090)
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output format

Comment: An example can be                                                                              
Einstein
Feynmann
Gell-Mann
Thorne
Lorentz
Planck
Hilbert
Poincare
Noether                                                                                                                                                                                                or                                                                                                            
Hilbert
Einstein
Feynmann
Gell-Mann
Poincare
Thorne
Lorentz
Planck
Noether

Comment: To get the JSON data out of the request, you need to do something like `inList = json.loads(request.json)['inList']` instead of `smarter[] = json.loads(inList['smarter'])`.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. `json`, `flask`, `post` tags are there just because the problem was encounterted is in that context? Isn't the problem just to get from the dictionary at the beginning of the question a list of names ordered on how smart they are (which is a pure _Python_ problem)? Or am I missing something? Also, there are some errors in the code (and indenting is poor, which can be disastrous in _Python_).